# How to push changes to an un-merged PR?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm using a git alias by which I can get an un-merged PR to my local computer. This is what the alias looks like:

```
    pr = "!f() { git co better-master && 
git fetch origin && 
git fetch upstream && 
git fetch upstream pull/${1}/head:pr-${1} && 
git co pr-${1} && 
git fetch upstream && 
git merge upstream/master; }; 
f"
```

This works great, however, I am not sure how to make a commit to an open PR. After I do `git pr 2767`, I am in branch called `pr-2767`. I make some code changes and want to push these code changes to the PR so that they show up in github.

How can I do that?

The open PR reads the following:

> SomeUsername wants to merge 3 commits into somerepo:master from
>   SomeUsername:somebranch

Answer (score 1):

So, basically what you need to do is to commit Your changes and push them to the branch that is going to be merged in PR, so in Your case `somebranch`. What You need to rembeber is to use the correct repository to push Your changes to, if You have forked the project and You are trying to merge the branch from Your fork to the main repo, You need to push the changes to YOUR forked repository not the main one.

Comment: I got it working by doing `git push remote pr-2767:somebranch`